# Am I instantiating pointers correctly in my add function of my Heap Implementation in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm not sure why my add function is resulting in numerous memory leaks, invalid reads and invalid writes. Of course, it includes several other functions in it, so I am including them as well. I hate to upload so much of my code, but I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong here.

heap.h header file:

```
struct Entry {
  int key;
  char* value;
};

typedef struct Entry Entry;

struct Heap {
  int capacity;
  int size;
  Entry** elements;
};

typedef struct Heap Heap;
```

heap.c:

```
void add(Heap* h, int priority, char* val) {
  if (h->size >= h->capacity) {
    expandCapacity(h);
  }
  //insert at end of storage array and bubble up
  Entry* toAdd = calloc(1, sizeof(Entry*));
  toAdd->key = priority;
  toAdd->value = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
  toAdd->value = val;
  h->elements[h->size]=toAdd;
  h->size += 1;
  bubbleUp(h, h->size);
}
```

bubbleUp and swap were given functions, all I had to do was adapt them for this project and translate them to c, so there may have been an issue in doing that though they make sense to me logically.

```
void bubbleUp(Heap* h, int index) {
   if(index <= 0) { return; }
   Entry* e = h->elements[index];
   Entry* parent = h->elements[(index-1)/2];
   int comp = strcmp(e->value, parent->value);
   if(comp > 0) {
     swap(h, index, parent->key);
     bubbleUp(h, parent->key);
   }
   else {
     return;
   }
}

void swap(Heap* h, int index1, int index2) {
   Entry* tmp = h->elements[index1];
   h->elements[index1] = h->elements[index2];
   h->elements[index2] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Be assured that what you posted is not "much code". If it's the minimal code required to reproduce your problem, so be it. You should have included even a few more lines, namely the `#include` lines, which would allow us to paste the code into our IDE and be ready to go.

Comment: I guess I was trying to say I feel I'm not at the point to ask for help if I need to paste so much code, but I also know that doesn't necessarily carry a correlation. I tell myself if I'm pasting basically my whole program then I probably don't understand something fundamental and need to keep figuring it out myself, but I'm thankful for your assurance and telling me this. I'll definitely not cut things out from now on.

Comment: Something you _should_ do before posting code here is to read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, which also helps in general when reporting problems.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll do that. I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
void add(Heap* h, int priority, char* val) {
    if (h->size >= h->capacity) {
        expandCapacity(h);
    }
    //insert at end of storage array and bubble up
    Entry* toAdd = calloc(1, sizeof(Entry*));
    toAdd->key = priority;
    toAdd->value = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    toAdd->value = val;
    h->elements[h->size]=toAdd;
    h->size += 1;
    bubbleUp(h, h->size);
}
```

you want to allocate memory for one struct Entry, not for its pointer so this would do the job

```
Entry* toAdd = calloc(1, sizeof(Entry));
```

You don't need to allocate memory for the pointer `toAdd->value` because it was already **statically** allocated by the compiler.

At this point, if you want to copy the pointer just remove this line `toAdd->value = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));` 
Instead, if you want to copy the content of the string you have to use `strncpy`

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory leak.  A block is allocated and then immediately lost.  I would just delete the first line.

```
toAdd->value = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
toAdd->value = val;
```

Also, you should allocate `sizeof(Entry)` here, not size of a pointer.

```
Entry* toAdd = calloc(1, sizeof(Entry*));
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Really appreciate!